# Problem (solved): ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xzy' after modifying module in google colab

Tags: python, module, google-colaboratory, modulenotfounderror

When importing modules from .py files into google colab I had the problem that when I modified the functions inside those modules in the google colab editor I couldn't load them into google colab after saving the new version of the .py file.

Solution: After every update of a module or package I needed to **restart the runtime**. After the restart the modules were accessible to import into the google colab script.

Another helpful advise is to add the folder where the modules are located to the sys.path

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/content/folder')
```

Comment: I really suggest dividing this question into two parts: question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the module with `importlib`

```py
import xyz # your module
import importlib

# Reload module before using it
importlib.reload(xyz)
```

Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) for further information